# Calculating Unique events in Google-Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

How can one find the count of unique events in Big Query ? I am having a hard time calculating the count of Unique events and matching it with GA interface.

Comment: It seems the number is not unique at a user or session level.

Defnition as per GA is not very clear :
The number of unique events per category, action, or label.

Comment: GA interface provides you sampled values, you you won't be able to match.

Answer (score 2):

two ways how this is used:

1) One is as the original linked documentation says, to combine full visitor user id, and their different session id: visitId, and count those.

```
SELECT
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(combinedVisitorId)
FROM (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(fullVisitorId,string(VisitId)) AS combinedVisitorId
  FROM
    [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910]
  WHERE
    hits.type='PAGE' )
```

2) The other is just counting distinct fullVisitorIds

```
SELECT
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(fullVisitorId)
FROM
  [google.com:analytics-bigquery:LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_20130910]
WHERE
  hits.type='PAGE'
```