# Users group by landing page Big query does not match with GA UI report

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm query about total users group by landing page on Big query on a specific date range (2018/1/1 to 2018/1/31).
But the result is not match with Google Analytics report from UI, at some records.
Result at GA:
[GA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBmro.png)

Result at big query
[Big query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh5p3.png)
The query I've made on BQ:

```
SELECT
hits.page.pagePath AS LandingPage,
EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT( fullVisitorId) AS Users
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXXXXX.YYYYYY], TIMESTAMP('2018/1/1'),TIMESTAMP('2018/1/31')))
WHERE
hits.type = 'PAGE'
AND hits.isEntrance = TRUE
GROUP BY
LandingPage
ORDER BY
Users DESC
```

So, Why this is not match between GA vs BQ?
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: what happens if you add `AND totals.visits = 1` in your where clauses?

Comment: Hi @Willian. Thank you, the result is same on Big query, mean nothing happens

Comment: Have you tried to add on the Where the clause totals.visits is not null

Comment: Hi @KemenPaulosPlaza, I've add but nothing change.

Comment: This question looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34606100/6253347

Comment: Did you use unsampled reports for comparison instead of the normal ones?

Comment: I can see that more amount of data is loaded via Google Analytics. Since in the GA, you have to set the time (hours and minutes) which you do not have to not have to set in BigQuery, I was wondering if the time interval is not the same between two scenarios. It can be justified by doing Query only on date 2018/1/31, and see the results. If the results are equal to around 300 `/` and only one `/it/`. Then you can conclude that there is a  no synchronization between the time intervals.

Comment: Hi @ShahinVNia, how can you add time (hour and minute) on GA? I've test on GA for a specific day for  on date 2018/1/01 and on date 2018/1/02, then a specific range from date 2018/1/01 to 2018/1/02, but the sum of specific for a page does not match between sum of two day and range. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @MartinWeitzmann, I use normal report, and it get 100% sessions for calculated (not get the sample sessions for create report).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for support everyone,
I've checked this issues, and the reason for not match between two scenarios is GA has show the sample reports on custom report.
I extract unsample report from custom report and get the result same with BQ.
But the problem is, on the custom report, It notice the custom report is created by 100% of sessions.